# Duplicate 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ria

I am using EntityFramework version 4.4, code first and I have created my data model in a separate project (MyApp.DataModel).
Because I am building a Silverlight application, I am using a WCF RIA services. The code required by the ria services is in a different project (MyApp.Services). This project has a reference to MyApp.DataModel.

An example of an data model:

```
   [Column("Remaining")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public virtual decimal? Remaining
    {
       //
    }
```

When I build MyApp.Services I get an error

Duplicate 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' attribute

Indeed, in the generated code there are two attributes

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

If I remove DatabaseGenerated, then on insert I get an error 
 The column "Remaining" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.

Any idea why and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx , `Key` already defaults to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`, so you wouldn't need to add the DatabaseGenerated separately.

Excerpt from the part under *DatabaseGenerated*:

> a key property will become an identity key in the database. That would
>   be the same as setting DatabaseGenerated to
>   DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity. If you do not want it to be an
>   identity key, you can set the value to DatabaseGenerationOption.None.

To be honest, I haven't tested this, but can you confirm that after removing [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] , the other attribute still remains in the generated code?

Comment: Thank you.. I have read the documentation more carefully and tested that situation and you were right. [Key] already defaults to DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity.

Comment: I have another problem but this time with databasegenerated.computed. I have edited my first post. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mark the property as DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity the EF understand that this is the key attribute.
Actually if you don't place none attribute (Key or DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity) the EF will assume that this is the id as the property ends with 'ID' and will create a autoincrement field at database.
The DataAnnotations are optional in many cases (like yours).
You also don't need to mark this property as virtual as it's a primitive type. Use virtual just to associate others classes (lazy load).

Comment: I have another problem  but this time with databasegenerated.computed. I have edited my first post.. I would appreciate your help.